# Why does my bullets not travel in my pygame program?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a simple 2d game in python using pygame. This game is a remnant of alien invasion, where one shoots the aliens before they reach the bottom of the screen. The game compiles and runs, but the issue I am having is with regards to the bullets. They are not traversing the screen. The problem started after I added code to make the aliens move. I tried adjusting the speed of the bullet but that didn't work. Below is a link to my gist with all the modules I am using. Any ideas as to how I can make the bullets move?

https://gist.github.com/dewest91/1d5d5ee538a4f68bfacc84c4081c24f8

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you never actually call the `update` method of the `Bullet` object.

I suspect you want to do it in the `update_bullets` function so here is the fix.

```
def update_bullets(aliens, bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
   #Check for any bullets that have hit aliens.
   #If so, get rid of the bullet and the alien.
   collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, False, True)


    #Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        bullet.update()
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

    print(len(bullets))
```

I would recommend changing `for bullet in bullets.copy()` to `for bullet in bullets`. As it the copy method doesn't change anything! If you don't believe me add a `print(bullets)` before and after the change: you'll see that in this context `.copy()` is just a waste of time, memory and is bad coding form.

Comment: Thanks Claymore, that did it!